# I am trying to split the text into paragraphs, it is splitting on commas instead of new line or paragraph

Tags: java

I am using following code. It is showing me output in commas and not spliting into new lines. I am getting text from DB. But the same code is working on my friend's eclipse .Please help me with this.

```
public static List<String> convertParagraphs(String text){

    List <String> convertedList= new ArrayList<String>();



    String[] paragraphs= text.split("\\|");

    convertedList= Arrays.asList(paragraphs);
    System.out.println("paj"+convertedList.toString());
    return convertedList;
```

Input from DB:

```
Testing|The|Results
```

It is showing Output:

```
[Testing, The, Results]
```

Please help me on this

Comment: You are `toString`-ing an array, the default behaviour is exactly what you are seeing: a comma separated string of the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, and your current output is also expected.  What you are seeing is just the default behavior for when `println` is called on a list of strings.  If you want each element of the list on a new line, iterate that list and do just that:

```
for (String item : convertedList) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

In Java 8 or higher you could try:

```
convertedList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split a string by line break by using the following statement :

```
public static List<String> convertParagraphs(String text){

    List <String> convertedList= new ArrayList<String>();



    String[] paragraphs= text.split("\\r\\n|\\n|\\r");

    convertedList= Arrays.asList(paragraphs);
    System.out.println("paj"+convertedList.toString());
    return convertedList;
```

Comment: The input text given in the OP uses pipes, not newlines/carriage returns.  But besides that, the confusion is due to the CSV output when directly printing a raw list of strings.

Comment: Still same issue